# Network Manager dispatcher.d script error

Tags: networking, firefox, scripts, network-manager

I wrote a script in "/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d" to open the Firefox preferences dialog whenever I connect to a particular network (college wifi), because I have to enable proxy.

The script is returning with "error code 1" in the logger. If I comment out the "firefox --preferences" line, the script runs and the "FIREFOX SCRIPT EXECUTED" text is displayed in the logger. How do I rectify it? Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "$0: called with no interface" 1>&2 
    exit 1;
fi


case "$2" in
    up|vpn-up)
    if [ "$CONNECTION_UUID" = "6e7f613f-5563-48f7-892d-655e95c0b834" ]; then
        firefox -preferences
        logger -s "FIREFOX SCRIPT EXECUTED"
    fi
    ;;
   down|vpn-down)
    ;;
   hostname)
   # Do nothing
   exit 0
       ;;
   hostname|dhcp4-change|dhcp6-change)
       # Do nothing
   ;;
   *)
    echo "$0: called with unknown action \`$2'" 1>&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem is that the call of `firefox --preferences` stops the script. Second problem is the script is executed as root not as the logged in user. Third: Firefox needs the users environment as well as the display number.

Change the "up"-part in the script as follows:

```
case "$2" in
    up|vpn-up)
    if [ "$CONNECTION_UUID" = "6e7f613f-5563-48f7-892d-655e95c0b834" ]; then
        export HOME=/home/user
        export DISPLAY=:0
        nohup sudo -u user firefox --preferences &
        logger -s "FIREFOX SCRIPT EXECUTED"
    fi
    ;;
```